# Figuring out the following equality: $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (1 + x^2)^{-m} dx= \int^{1}_{0}(v^{m - \frac{3}{2}}(1-v)^{-\frac{1}{2}}) dv$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have problem with this integral. I cannot figure out the first equality.  Any suggestions?
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (1 + x^2)^{-m} dx= \int^{1}_{0}(v^{m - \frac{3}{2}}(1-v)^{-\frac{1}{2}}) dv=B\left(\frac{1}{2}, m - \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
The substitution is:
$$v=\frac{1}{(1 + x^2)}$$

Comment: I cant figure first equality

Comment: Back substitute for $x$ in the second integral, and then look for a way to get between the two forms

Comment: It is worth mention that 

$$B(x,y) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{x-1}}{(1+t)^{x+y}}\,dx$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider splitting your integral in two (We do this because when we rearrange for $x$ on the substitution, we have to consider the cases where the sign is negative or positive).
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (1 + x^2)^{-m} dx=\color{red}{\int_{-\infty}^0 (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx}+\color{green}{\int_0^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx} \tag{1}$$
Using the proposed substitution, we obtain:
$$v=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\iff x=\begin{cases} -\frac{\sqrt{1-v}}{\sqrt{v}} & \text{if } x<0 \\ \frac{\sqrt{1-v}}{\sqrt{v}} & \text{if } x\geq0 \end{cases}\iff dx=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v}\cdot v^{3/2}}~dv & \text{if } x< 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v}\cdot v^{3/2}} ~dv & \text{if } x\geq 0\end{cases}$$
Taking the appropriate substitution for the red and green integrals, we have:
$$\color{red}{\int_{-\infty}^0 (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx}=\int_0^1 v^m\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v}\cdot v^{3/2}}~dv=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 v^{m-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot (1-v)^{-1/2}~dv \tag{2.1}$$
And:
$$\color{green}{\int_0^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx}=\int_1^0 v^m\cdot -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v}\cdot v^{3/2}} ~dv=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 v^{m-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot (1-v)^{-1/2}~dv \tag{2.2}$$
Adding the two together, we obtain the result you require.
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (1 + x^2)^{-m} dx=\int_0^1 v^{m-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot (1-v)^{-1/2}~dv}$$
I'm sure you can continue with the second step.

---

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can realise that $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{-m}$ is an even function. Therefore, we have:
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} (1 + x^2)^{-m} dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx+\int_0^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx=2\int_0^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-m}~dx$$
Hence, we only need to consider the case where $x\geq 0$, which has already been evaluated in $(2.2)$.
$$v=\frac{1}{1+x^2} \iff x=\frac{\sqrt{1-v}}{\sqrt{v}}\iff dx=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-v}\cdot v^{3/2}} ~dv$$

Comment: Good post. Note that it is a lot easier to go backwards though, as I noted in my comment above and my post. Nevertheless, if such a trick was not known ahead of time I would follow your steps as shown here. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is a LOT easier if we work backwards.
If we back-substitute using $v = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ we get
$$\int^{1}_{0}v^{m - \frac{3}{2}}(1-v)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dv = \int_{\infty}^0 \frac{(1+x^2)^{1/2}}{x(1+x^2)^{m - \frac{3}{2}}} \frac{-2x dx}{(1+x^2)^2} = 2\int_0^\infty (1+x^2)^{-m} dx$$
This last integral can be easily converted to the OP's form by noting the integral is Even.

---

*It is worth noting that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} = 0$ as well, but we can exclude negative infinity for a few reasons, such as that it makes our function negative and that we are approaching $0$ from the positive direction.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no mystery.

$$v=\frac1{1+x^2}\iff x=\pm\sqrt{\frac1v-1}$$ and

$$dx=\pm\frac12\sqrt{\frac v{v-1}}\frac{-dv}{v^2}$$

which you integrate for $v\in(1,0)$ twice.